# launch not called after settings change when developing Rally app externally

Tags: javascript, rally

I am developing a Rally custom app externally as described [here](https://help.rallydev.com/apps/2.1/doc/#!/guide/developing_externally) and the app is not updating after changing settings manually.  I am going into the settings form, changing my settings, and clicking save to update them.  When running the application in the Rally custom HTML Panel, the app works correctly.

I noticed that after a settings change in the custom HTML panel, the app calls the `launch` function, however, when running the app externally it does not.  I suspect this is the culprit.  Does anyone know how to fix this or if there is a workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a little bit of a weird one for sure.  The ability to edit app settings in an external app was a fairly late-breaking feature in sdk 2.1 and as such we never got to fully close the loop on making that seamless.

What we did manage to get done though, is the onSettingsUpdate template method, which serves as a hook for your exact use case:

https://help.rallydev.com/apps/2.1/doc/#!/api/Rally.app.App-method-onSettingsUpdate

That method will be invoked on your app class with the newly saved settings.  Then you can re-render your app in response to the new values.

The weird part is that this method is really only for the development phase and will never be called when running an app internally within Rally.

Comment: That did the trick.  For a quick work-around I called `removeAll()` then `launch()` in the `onSettingsUpdate` function.  I needed the to call `removeAll` to remove the previous chart so you can see the new one.